# How do I remove the first 8 characters from a Microsoft Access database field?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I've got an Access '07 database that imports data from text files. The problem is one of the fields that is taken in comes with a date value before a place value that I don't need. For example, the field comes in like so: 01012010DUBLIN whereas I need it to just display DUBLIN.

I'm stumped on this and any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Is every date encoded as 8 digits? Or is it variable?

Comment: How is this data being imported? Is there a custom VBA function? Is it done manually with the import wizard?

Comment: The text files are imported through a VBA function, and the field comes in as a text value with 8 digits before the value I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your skill level is, but the *easiest* approach would be to import the data to a temporary table, and then do a make-table query.  On the make-table query, bring that column in using mid() function:

```
mid([your field name], 9, [max number of chars to span])
```

This will truncate the text starting at the 9th character in your field.

Note - You could skip the temp table part and just run an update query on your imported data using the same mid() function.

Comment: That worked great with the UPDATE function. Thanks a million!